# Facebook Javascript SDK: Error validating access token when posting to feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, feed, posting

I'm trying to implement posting to a user's feed from my website. I am using the Javascript SDK and have managed to get myself logged in, and granted both publish_stream and publish_actions permissions. However when I call the /me/feed post action, I get the following error as the response:

```
code: 190
error_subcode: 467
message: "Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error."
```

I am using the client-side authentication model from here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/

This is the FB.api feed post code I'm using:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: 'Testing FB feed posting' }, function(response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error');
        console.log(response);
    }
    else {
        alert('Posted');
    }
});
```

I've checked the application settings and the domain is set right. I've also double checked that I have permissions to do this post. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong please?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try checking the FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { //do code here });